# Sending a string of attachments from a table

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I have a database which stores amongst other things, medical declaration forms of my clients.

The forms are stored externally in a folder (`c:\...\medical form`) and are titled (`DDMMYYYY Fname Lname`).  This file name (not `strpath`) data is stored in `[med forms]`.

On the parent form (`courses`) I am trying to put a button which cycles through `[med forms]` on the subform `[courses customer subform]`, attaching them to a email which is then sent to me.

I'm having trouble cycling through the form and connecting the `strpath` and `strfile` to attach these documents.

```
Dim appOutLook As Outlook.Application
Dim MailOutLook As Outlook.MailItem
Dim strpath As String
Dim strfile As String
Dim varSubject As Variant
Dim varGroup As Variant
Dim varBody As Variant
Dim stratt As String
strpath = "C:\...\Medical forms"
varSubject = "Med forms " & (Me.[Title]) & (Me.[Start])
varBody = "email body TBC"
    With Me.[courses customer subform].Form.RecordsetClone
    If (.RecordCount) Then
        .MoveFirst
        Do Until .EOF
            If Len(![Med form]) Then
                stratt = stratt & strpath & ![Med form]
            End If
        .MoveNext
        Loop
        If Len(strEmail) Then

    Set appOutLook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set MailOutLook = appOutLook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With MailOutLook
        .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText
        .To = "info@myemail.co.uk"
        
        .Subject = varSubject
        .HTMLBody = varBody
        .Attachments.Add (strpath & strfile)
        .Display
    End With
End sub
```

Comment: Please don't use spaces when naming objects. will save you a lot of trouble in the future :)

Comment: In all fairness I created this DB as I learned to use access, I definitely know that for future reference now :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already using late binding (`CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`) I would suggest using late binding throughout the rest of your Sub (avoiding the need to add the library reference), and would suggest something along the lines of the following:

```
Sub EmailForms()
    Dim strPth As String: strPth = "C:\...\Medical forms\"
    Dim strSub As String: strSub = "Med forms " & Me.[Title] & Me.[Start]
    Dim strBdy As String: strBdy = "email body TBC"

    Dim rsRst As DAO.Recordset
    Set rsRst = Me.[courses customer subform].Form.RecordsetClone
    If Not rsRst.BOF And Not rsRst.EOF Then
        rsRst.MoveFirst

        Dim olApp As Object
        Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

        With olApp.CreateItem(0) 'olMailItem
            .BodyFormat = 3 'olFormatRichText
            .to = "info@myemail.co.uk"
            .Subject = strSub
            .HTMLBody = strBdy

            With .Attachments
                Do Until rsRst.EOF
                    If rsRst![Med form] <> vbNullString Then
                        .Add strPth & rsRst![Med form]
                    End If
                    rsRst.MoveNext
                Loop
            End With

            .Display
        End With
    End If
    rsRst.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Checking for`Not rs.EOF`may fail if someone does weird things like`rs.MoveLast`and`rs.MoveNext`after that (then rs.EOF is True) so better check for`Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the speedy response, I'm not the best at this and only really do it for my own little projects so it's a massive help!  I've also added in a couple more bits such as attaching a course register.  Again thanks so much for the help.